# how i can create report on knowledge article with article types ( ex :Product Advice)?

Tags: reporting, servicecloud, joined-reports

how i can create report on knowledge article with article types ex: product advice?how i can create report on knowledge article with article types ( ex :Product Advice)?

Comment: welcome to SFSE; check out [ask] to get the most from the Community

Answer (score 1):

Refer to below these links. It helps you.

**App by Salesforce**

*This package provides reports and dashboards that help you monitor your knowledge base. For example, you can compare article ratings and views, analyze recent activity by authors, and determine which articles are helping solve the most cases.*
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HXO9EAO

*Use Salesforce Knowledge custom reports to track how articles are created, maintained, and delivered.*
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=knowledge_custom_reports.htm

Comment: Please do not post link only answers include a quick summary of what each link contains.